# submit is not working after adding a code to prevent double submit JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/abude/TKtKq/1/)

before i added the line:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

was working(sending the info with the post) , after i added that disable stuff to prevent double clicking, the form won't send the info but the disable is working and FORM **not**

please tell me, did i added wrong the line 5 ? should i add the disable code in another place ?

**STILL NO SOLUTION !**

Comment: When working with submit alway remember to return true or false

Comment: In the fiddle it looks like it get disabled and then reloads. This is what you want, right?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu: In a jQuery event handler, returning anything but `false` is identical to returning nothing at all.

Comment: i want to prevent double click on the button and after i added that code the form isn't submitting.

Answer (score 2):

You must return true, to execute the submit:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return true;
});
```

Check [jQuery submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), it says:

> This happens prior to the actual submission, so we can cancel the
>   submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by
>   returning false from our handler.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not the case. I thought the contract was "return `false` to cancel, otherwise continue"

Comment: **-1** Returning nothing does not mean returning `false`

Comment: I thought the contract is return true to do it, return false to prevent it. If you don't write an explicit return the method will return undefined which is falsy in JS. But the browsers could of course test for false like this: `returnValue !== false` or something.

Comment: @TimBüthe: That's exactly what jQuery does. When the documentation says `false`, it means `false`, not falsy.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is:

```
 onclick="return checkDuplicateMessage()"
```

Don't combine jQuery and inline event handlers.

Instead, go for:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    //cancel the submit if there's a duplicate
    if(!checkDuplicateMessage())
        return false;

    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: @Jimmy: Put your `onclick` logic in the same place? (the `.submit` handler)

Comment: Eric, i'm not very good, can you please update your code so i can see exactly what do you mean. Thanks!

Comment: Eric, now it's not working at all, the click on the button does nothing neither submit nor disable

Comment: @Jimmy: Then `checkDuplicateMessage` is erroring/returning false. That's not my code, it's yours.

Comment: Eric, the code was working, i just added the disable code to disable the button exact after submit to not allow double click on the button.

Comment: Based on the OP's jsFiddle, he's using jQuery 1.26, however, `.prop()` is only good in jQuery 1.6 and above.

Comment: @Jimmy: The latest version of jQuery (1.7.2), or `attr` instead of `prop`.

Comment: i tried but still not working at all, the submit does nothing now... even in jsfiddle not working ...